# Get output vars for standalone ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to get the current values for a standalone ARM template without using PowerShell, and without resorting to running `az deployment group create`?

Standalone means that the ARM template is NOT linked to any other ARM templates.  Instead, a standalone ARM template is just run one-off on a standalone basis.

Our requirement is that we NOT use PowerShell or other dependencies.

We are looking for something that is equivalent to `terraform output` but for ARM templates.

Given that there is a way to do this with PowerShell, there must be some other easy way.  Perhaps using the CLI, or perhaps with some custom function.

Comment: Hey @CodeMed have you gone through this link by any chance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/outputs?tabs=azure-powershell#get-output-values

Comment: A template doesn't have outputs in its own right. A deployment record has outputs, and those can be accessed with az cli as described by Craig McGregor in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Has the deployment already run?
Do you know the name of the deployment?

If so you should be able to use:
`az deployment group show`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/deployment/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-deployment-group-show

https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2021/12/28/azure-cli-show-query-output-properties

Answer (score 0):

A template must be linked in order to produce outputs.

Just nested template doesn't produce outputs, you'll get an error if will try to reference it:

> The language expression property 'outputs' doesn't exist, available properties are 'template, templateHash, parameters, mode, debugSetting, provisioningState, validationLevel'.